# Boot 15.10 Live ISO from HDD

Tags: 15.10, live-environment

**Ubuntu 15.10 Live ISO** doesn't load from my **non-linux partition**, but **12.04 iso** does boot.

Here's my **40_custom** script for 12.04:

```
menuentry "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" {
loopback loop (hd0,3)/ISOFOLDER/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ISOFOLDER/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso file=(loop)/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

and it boots fine from the **GRUB menu**. But not for 15.10 iso:

```
menuentry "ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso" {
isofile="/ISOFOLDER/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

once selected from GRUB, it loads to black screen then restarts the PC. I understand loading **32 bit iso** has a different script from **64 bit**. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a better look at the way you mount the `hd0,3`.

I think it would be more like:

```
(hd0,gpt1,msdos1)
(hd0,gpt1,msdos1)
(hd0,gpt1,apple1)
(hd0,msdos)
```

But I think you cannot use (hd0,1) or like you show:

```
loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile
```

should be more like...

```
loopback loop (hd0,gpt3)$isofile
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set a root, so **iso-scan/filename** can't detect the iso file.

First try it on the grub> prompt. So you could find if the loopback actually works.

Run the following commands on grub command-line..

```
loopback loop (hd0,3)/ISOFOLDER/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=(hd0,3)/ISOFOLDER/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```